# Color of the triangle view drawn by UIBezierPath does not change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to draw a triangle view and change the filled color programmatically.

Following is my code.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let triangleView = TriangleView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        triangleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                    y: 100,
                                    width: 50,
                                    height: 50)
        self.view.addSubview(triangleView)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        triangleView.drawColor(color: .yellow)
    }
}


class TriangleView: UIView {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        print("TriangleView draw")
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: self.bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.close()
        
        self.drawColor(color: .green)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    func drawColor(color: UIColor) {
        print("TriangleView drawColor")

        color.setFill()
        path.lineWidth = 0
        path.fill()
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

In this code, `TriangleView` draws a triangle filled with green color.

After that, `ViewController` changes filled color by yellow.

Following the result.

[image]

There are two problems.

1. Background color is black though expectation is `clear`.
2. Triangle color is not changed to `yellow`.

Could anyone give me advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`

```
class TriangleView: UIView {
    
    private var triangleColor: UIColor = .green {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        print("TriangleView draw")
        self.backgroundColor = .white // Set any background color
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        context.saveGState()
        defer { context.restoreGState() }
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: self.bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.close()
        
        context.addPath(path.cgPath)
        context.setFillColor(triangleColor.cgColor)
        context.closePath()
        context.closePath()
        context.fillPath()
        context.restoreGState()
    }
    
    func drawColor(color: UIColor) {
        triangleColor = color
    }
}
```

Or you can use `CAShapeLayer`

```
class TriangleView: UIView {
    
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.initialConfig()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initialConfig()
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        print("TriangleView draw")
        self.shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
        drawShape()
    }
    
    private func initialConfig() {
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    
    private func drawShape() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: self.bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.close()
        
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
    
    func drawColor(color: UIColor) {
        self.shapeLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` doesn't work for me. The background color becomes still black when `ViewController` doesn't call `drawColor`. However, `CAShapeLayer` works fine! I'll use it instead of mine. Thank you!